# How to multiply a matrix by a known vector to return an array

Tags: r

Good afternoon!

Assume we have a vector and a matrix :

```
v = c(2,3,4)
[1] 2 3 4

m=matrix(1:9,ncol=3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I'm searching an efficient way ( or built-in function ) to get three matrices `m1 , m2 , m3` such that :

```
m1=v[1]*m
m2=v[2]*m
m3=v[3]*m
```

We could obtain this using a 3d-array :

```
my_fct<-function(m,v){

f=array(data=rep(NA,nrow(m)*ncol(m)*length(v)),dim = c(nrow(m),ncol(m),length(v)))

for (j in c(1:length(v))){

f[,,j]=v[j]*m

}
return(f)
}

my_fct(m,v)

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    8   14
[2,]    4   10   16
[3,]    6   12   18

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3   12   21
[2,]    6   15   24
[3,]    9   18   27

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4   16   28
[2,]    8   20   32
[3,]   12   24   36
```

I hope my request is clear!

Thank you a lot for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'v' is a vector and we want each element to be multiplied by the same `matrix` 'm', an option is to loop over the element of 'v' and do the multiplication

```
lapply(v, `*`, m)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    8   14
[2,]    4   10   16
[3,]    6   12   18

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3   12   21
[2,]    6   15   24
[3,]    9   18   27

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4   16   28
[2,]    8   20   32
[3,]   12   24   36
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @akrun , problem solved !

Comment: Done , Thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option

```
> Map(`*`, list(m), v)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    8   14
[2,]    4   10   16
[3,]    6   12   18

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3   12   21
[2,]    6   15   24
[3,]    9   18   27

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4   16   28
[2,]    8   20   32
[3,]   12   24   36
```